# Using select method in form_for in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, form-for

I would like to use a method inside a form_for in rails to create a select tag with options where the value of the options come from one array and the options enclosed by the option tags come from another array.

For example, the first option would be:

```
<option value = Array1[0]> Array2[0] </option>
```

How do I do this?  Can I use 'select' such as:

```
= form_for @activity do |f|
  = f.select(Array1, Array2, {:selected => nil, :prompt => 'Select Stage'})
```

I couldn't get something like this working, even though this format seemed consistent with options_for_select as described in the rails API at api.rubyonrails.org.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
= f.select(:method, Array2.zip(Array1), { :selected => nil, :prompt => 'Select Stage' })
```

The [zip](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) method will combine two arrays to make one two-dimensional array.

So, for example, `[1,2,3].zip([4,5,6])` will return `[[1,4], [2,5], [3,6]]`.

`select` can then interpret this as a list of option texts and option values.

Given `[['Male', 'm'], ['Female', 'f']]`, select will return

```
<option value="m">Male</option>
<option value="f">Female</option>
```

Comment: This worked!  Only thing is, to get it as I displayed in the question,  the order was Array2.zip(Array1).  If you switch that up, I'll accept and upvote.  Thanks!

Comment: Done. And added a more in depth explanation.